# Access 2007:Append Query which summarizes data from an Inventory Table

Tags: ms-access

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to make it work despite days of tinkering around and research.

I have an Inventory Table:

```
   Product    PrevInv   PrevOrder  OnHand   Cost
---------------------------------------------------
1 | Apples  |    1    |     2     |  2     | $1
2 | Pears   |    2    |     3     |  1     | $2
```

And so on for several hundred items. I want to append a weekly summary to a table called History in this manner:

```
    Period End   $Used   $Sales   $FoodCost
---------------------------------------
1 |  Date()    |  $9   |  $50   |   18%
```

Date() Will be the current date when the Query is run.

$Used  Will be a total sum of all inventory items useage (PrevInv + PrevOrder - OnHand) * Cost.

$Sales Will be a prompt for user input to enter sales from another program.

$FoodCost Will be $Used/$Sales

I want this all on one row. All I've managed to do is have it append an entry for every single inventory item individually. Also, I can't seem to get the $Sales user input to properly append.

I would offer some code as to what I've tried, but I've been through so many incorrect methods that I'm not sure I'd even have anything worthwhile to share.

Thanks in advance, this is really frustrating me.

Comment: You just need an aggregate query. Look up the SQL term.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following and see if that helps:

```
SELECT Date() AS [Period End], Sum((([PrevInv]+[PrevOrder]-[OnHand])*[Cost])) AS Used, [Enter Sales] AS Sales, Sum((([PrevInv]+[PrevOrder]-[OnHand])*[Cost])/[Enter Sales]) AS FoodCost
FROM Inventory
WHERE (((Inventory.Cost)>0))
GROUP BY Date(), [Enter Sales];
```

Comment: Great work, it's entering everything perfectly, except my FoodCost percent is always 100% or 0%. That might have to do with my table formatting, I'll look into it.  Thanks again!

Comment: What amount are you entering for sales when you run this? Given the above data, if I enter $2, I get 450% or if I enter 12, I get 75%.  (I changed the column definition to be 'Percent' with 2 decimal places)

Comment: Oh, you mean in your table that you append to? I am talking about the query I created. In the query builder I defined the format of each field as follows (left to right): Date, Fixed, Currency, Percent.  What's the chance your table field is defined as 'Long Integer' instead of 'Double'?

Comment: Edit: It was set to Long Integer. Changing it to Double works perfectly. Such a simple thing to get confused by, Thanks again Wayne!

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean the query or the table... what are you referring to? If you are referring to the table, then please change the query to a 'Select' query and manually run it to see what you get. If all looks good, then you just need to define the fields in the table properly.

Comment: In your 'Inventory' table, I would expect 'Type' of Text, Number, Number, Number,  Currency. and for table 'History', I would expect: Number, Date, Currency, Currency, Percent.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the table. I was making sure my data got saved properly before I created a query, which I just did as well. Everything looks great.

Yep, that's what I just set those field types to. Thanks again for your time, it means a lot.